# Find Between 2 JavaScript Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<script>
var array1 = ['2023-04-05','2023-04-06','2023-04-07'];    //array1
var array2 = ['2023-04-07'];    //array2
found1 = array1.find((val, index) => {    //find the date in array1
    return array2.includes(val);
});
$('.show').html(found1);
</script>
```

result 2023-04-07. How to result like this 2023-04-05, 2023-04-06

Comment: According to the docs `find` returns the first element of the array where the callback returns true ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get all elements in the first array not present in the second.

```js
let array1 = ['2023-04-05','2023-04-06','2023-04-07'];
let array2 = ['2023-04-07'];
let res = array1.filter(x => !array2.includes(x));
console.log(res);
```